# Removing images from RSS descriptions – trunica issue when using substr()

Tags: wordpress, rss

I'm pulling a facebook feed through RSS, but at times, posts have images in them that are hyperlinked to the post themselves.

When pulling the description and limiting it with substr `<?php echo substr($block->get_description(), 0, 170); ?>...`, it trunicates 170 characters in, not finishing the  tag and causes the rest of the page to break.

---

Is ther anyway of stripping out ? Perhaps substr isn't the right method of doing this